# Http Post Json - Array

Tags: arrays, angular

i am selecting a list of doctors that i want to group in a department for rural area. The selected doctors are then pushed into the array and saved to the database. i am able to selected and post to save in the database but there is a bit of flaw i am finding hard to resolve. 
My problem is when i select Doctor 1 and Doctor 2 and post to my service, the params sent to my service is counted 3. That is Doctor 1, Doctor 2, Doctor 2. Why is Doctor 2 being duplicated?

**selecting doctors**

```
 selectDoctors(Doctors){
            Doctors.listed = (Doctors.listed) ? false : true;
            this.deptList = Doctors

        }
```

**submitting group of selected doctors in array**

```
     Doctors: Doctors[] = [];

         hospital =   { 
                hospital_name : "",

                details : [{
            id: "",
            ward: "",
        }]
    }


    //submit data into array

     Object.keys(this.Doctors).filter(key => this.Doctors[key].selected)
                .forEach(key => {



                    this.hospital.details['0'].id = this.Doctors[key].id
                    this.hospital.details['0'].ward =this.Doctors[key].ward

                     this.groups.members.push(this.Doctors.['0']);

}
      this.http.categorizeDepartment(this.groups)
      .subscribe(data => {

});

}
```

Comment: Can you plase console.log() inside of forEach part and see does it get iterated for 3 times ?

Comment: Also are you trying to just overwrite the hospital.details with the last doctor in your array? Or is your intention to add each doctor's id and ward into a separate object in the array?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's some strange mutation and unnecessary methods being used here that the results are unpredictable. If all you want to do is put selected doctors into a group, you can do like this:

```
this.groups.members = [
   ...this.groups.members,
   this.Doctors.filter(doctor => doctor.selected)
];
```

If you also want to add the doctor's info to the first item in the hospital.details array, you can add that too:

```
let selectedDoctors = this.Doctors.filter(doctor => doctor.selected);

this.groups.members = [...this.groups.members, selectedDoctors];

for (let doctor of selectedDoctors) {
  this.hospital.details['0'].id = doctor.id
  this.hospital.details['0'].ward = doctor.ward
}
```